# Probability density that minimizes the sample range

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, oc.optimization-and-control

Let $\mathcal{F}$ denote the set of all "concave probability distributions" on the unit interval, that is, all functions $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f$ is concave, $f(x)\geq 0$ for all $x\in [0,1]$, and $\int_0^1 f(x) dx=1$.  Given a collection of $n$ samples $X_1 , \dots, X_n$, define $R(n) = \mathbf{E}( \max_i X_i - \min_i X_i )$ to be the expected length of the sample range of the samples $X_n$.  My question is:  what is the density $f^* \in \mathcal{F}$ that minimizes $R(n)$?  If that's too complicated, is there a useful lower bound for $R(n)$?

Comment: What about the density $f$ being a triangle-shaped function centered at $1/2$, of width $2\epsilon$ and height $1/\epsilon$? Then the range of a sample is almost surely less than $2\epsilon$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For $n$ i.i.d. random variables $X_1,\dots,X_n$ with (cumulative) distribution function $ F(x)= \int _ 0 ^ x  f(t)dt\,  $     we have
$\mathbb{P}(\max_ {1\le i \le n} X _i \le x) =  F(x)^n \, $, $\mathbb{P}(\min _ {1\le i \le n} X _ i \le x) =  1 - \big ( 1- F(x)\big) ^n \, . $ Therefore the random variables $\max _ {1\le i \le n} X _ i$ and $\max _ {1\le i \le n} X _i$ have density functions respectively $\big( F(x)^n\big)'$ and $\big(1 - \big (1- F(x)\big )^n\big)'\, .$ Therefore

$$ \mathbb{E} \big ( \max _ {1\le i \le n} X _ i - \min _ {1\le i \le n} X _ i\big ) =\mathbb{E} \big (\max_ {1\le i \le n} X _i \big )- \mathbb{E} \big (\min _ {1\le i \le n} X _ i\big ) = $$
$$\int_0^1 x\bigg( F ^ n + \big( 1-F \big)^ n  \bigg)'dx = 1 - \int_0^1 \bigg( F ^ n + \big( 1-F \big)^ n  \bigg)dx =\int _ 0 ^ 1 p\big(F(x)\big)dx \, ,
$$
after integration by parts; here $p(t)$ is the strictly concave polynomial function  $$p(t):= 1- t^n -(1-t)^n\, .$$

$$*$$

We have therefore to minimize the strictly concave functional 
$$J(f):=\int _ 0 ^ 1 p\Big( \int _ 0 ^ x  f dt\Big) dx \, , $$ on the convex  compact subset (see **1** below) $K\subset L^1([0,1])$ of all positive, concave, norm-one functions $f$.
A continuous strictly concave functional defined on a compact convex set $K$ attains its  infimum  on the extreme points of $K$. Here (see **2** below), the extreme points of $K$ are exactly the family of piecewise linear functions, for $\{f_c \}_ {0\le c\le 1} $,

$$ f_c(x):=   \frac{2x}{c}\mathrm{\quad if\quad } 0\le x\le c\, , $$
$$ f_c(x):=    \frac{2(1-x)}{1-c} \mathrm{\quad if\quad } c\le x\le 1\, .$$ 
The minimization problem is therefore reduced to the  computation of the one-variable maximum: $$\min _ {f\in K}    J(f )=\min _ {0\le c \le 1}    J(f_c) =1-\max _ {0\le c \le 1} g(c)\, ,$$

where $g(c)= 1-J(f_c)$ is 
$$g(c) =\int_0^1  \bigg( c^{n+1}x^{2n} + (1-c)^{n+1}x^{2n} + c( 1- cx^2 )^n +(1-c)\big( 1- (1-c)x^2 \big)^n \bigg) dx \, ;$$
so $g$ is a polynomial in $c$ symmetrical w.r.to $c=1/2$. It *should be true* that  $g$ is 
concave in $c$, so that one eventually finds
$$\min _ {f\in K}    J(f )=1  -\frac{1}{2^n(2n+1)} -  \int_0^1   \bigg( 1-  \frac{x^2}{2} \bigg)^n   dx \, .$$

For $n\to +\infty$ this is (see **3** below)
$$  1- \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2n}} + o\Big(\frac{1}{n}\Big)\, . $$

[image]

*Plots of the polynomials* $g(c)$, *for* $n=2,\dots,12$, *from top to bottom.*

$$*$$

**More details.**

**1.** *(Compactness of $K$).* Note that by definition of $K$, each $f\in K$ satisfies 
$$ 0 \le f(x) \le 2\\ ,$$ 
for all $x\in [0,1]$ and, for any $\epsilon > 0$,
$$\mathrm{Lip}\big(f,\\ [\epsilon, 1-\epsilon]\big) \le \frac{2}{\epsilon} \, ,$$
which is sufficient to conclude that $K$ is compact in $L^1$ by the Ascoli-Arzelà and  the dominated convergence theorems.

**2.** *(Extreme points of $K$).* Note that for any $f\in K$ and $c\in [0,1]$, we have $f=f_c$  if and only if $f(c)\ge 2 $. This implies that all these $f_c$'s are extreme points of $K$ (if $f_c$ is an arithmetic mean of two elements of $K$, at least one of them has value at $c$ not less than $2$, hence it is $f_c$ itself). Conversely, if $f\in K$ has $\|f\|_\infty < 2$, then  one can  find a non-zero function $h$ with $\int_0^1 hdx =0$ and such that $f\pm h $ are concave and non-negative, hence in $K$, so that $f =\frac{1}{2}\big((f+h)+(f-h)\big)$ is not extremal.

**3.** *(Asymptotics).* Incidentally, a quick asymptotics for $\int_0^1   \big( 1-  \frac{x^2}{2} \big) ^ n   dx$  as $n\to\infty$  comes from the dominated convergence theorem, recalling that $0\le (1+t/n)^n\le e^t$ as soon as $1+t/n\ge0$. Changing variable, $x:=\xi/\sqrt n$,

$$\int_0^1   \bigg( 1-  \frac{x^2}{2} \bigg) ^ n   dx = \sqrt{\frac{1}{n}} \int _ 0 ^{+\infty}   \bigg( 1-  \frac {\xi^2}{2n} \bigg) ^ n  \chi _ {[0,\sqrt n]}(\xi) d\xi $$

$$= \sqrt{\frac{1}{n}} \int _ 0  ^{+\infty}    e^ {  -\xi^2/2 } d\xi \, \big(1+ o(1)\big) = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2n}}+ o(\frac{1}{n})\, .$$

Comment: thank you, plugging this into maple suggests that $R \sim 1-n^{-2}$ and that the optimal $c$ is $1/2$!

Comment: I agree, I added some more details.

Comment: (by the way, I found R∼ 1−√(π/2n) , e.g. for n=10, R(10)=0.61.. and 1−√(π/20)=0.60..)